# Create VisualBrush by code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, visualbrush

I have this example as XAML:

```
<VisualBrush x:Key="HatchBrush" TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,5,5" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="0,0,5,5" ViewboxUnits="Absolute" po:Freeze="True">
<VisualBrush.Visual>
<Path Data="M 0 5 L 5 0 M -2 2 L 2 -2 M 3 7 L 7 3"
    Stroke="#80ffffff" StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
    RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" />
</VisualBrush.Visual>
```

I need to write the same in code behind but I've been able to do only this:

```
            VisualBrush vb = new VisualBrush();
        vb.Viewport = new Rect(0, 0, 5, 5);
        vb.TileMode = TileMode.Tile;
```

Honestly I dunno how to write the Path Data. How can I do this?

Comment: is `Path` constant or does it depend on some parameters? if constant: define it as a resource and pick that resource in code to assign Visual

Comment: Path is constant but the reason I have to do in code behind is that I need to combine with already existing Brush with solidcolor; I would draw bended lines over a solidcolor fill.

Comment: That's not a "reason" to do it in code. A DrawingBrush would allow to use multiple different drawings in a DrawingGroup.

Answer (score 1):

You could write

```
vb.Visual = new Path
{
    Data = Geometry.Parse("M 0 5 L 5 0 M -2 2 L 2 -2 M 3 7 L 7 3"),
    Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0x80, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff))
};
```

However, you don't need to use a VisualBrush at all.

The XAML below shows how to use a DrawingBrush with two drawings to get the hatch pattern on top of a solid color background.

```
<DrawingBrush x:Key="HatchBrush" TileMode="Tile"
              Viewport="0,0,5,5" ViewportUnits="Absolute"
              Viewbox="0,0,5,5" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <DrawingGroup>
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="DarkCyan">
                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,5,5"/>
                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
            </GeometryDrawing>
            <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M0,5 L5,0 M-2,2 L2,-2 M3,7 L7,3">
                <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                    <Pen Brush="#80ffffff" Thickness="1"/>
                </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
            </GeometryDrawing>
        </DrawingGroup>
    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>
```